# Laravel Carbon: Wrong date: 1 day difference

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, strftime, php-8.1

I'm trying to use Laravel Carbon because strftime() will be deprecated in PHP 8.1.
A simple example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::setLocale('nl');
Carbon::now('Europe/Amsterdam');

$date = '1665525600';
```

when I use `strftime("%A %e %B %Y", $date)`; the output is

> woensdag 12 oktober 2022

and when I use `Carbon::parse($date)->isoFormat('dddd D MMMM YYYY')`; the output is

> dinsdag 11 oktober 2022

How is this possible and how do I fix this?

Comment: `Carbon::parse` can't parse from a timestamp. You want `Carbon::createFromTimestamp`. But other than that, it sounds like the timezone that `strftime` uses is different than what Carbon is set to.

Comment: use createFromTimestamp .Carbon::createFromTimestamp($date)->format('l d F Y')

Comment: BTW, you should be setting the timezone in the ``app/config.php`` file.

Comment: timezone is the same, but your answer helpt me. `Carbon::createFromTimestamp($datum)->isoFormat('dddd D MMMM YYYY' )` is correct now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::now('Europe/Amsterdam');` in your code is doing nothing, it creates an object that is never used.

Timestamps are UTC by nature, so you always get an UTC date

To get the correct date in Amsterdam for this timestamp, here are your 2 alternatives:

```
Carbon::setLocale('nl');

$date = '1665525600';

// either
echo Carbon::parse("@$date")->tz('Europe/Amsterdam')->isoFormat('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
// or
echo Carbon::createFromTimestamp($date, 'Europe/Amsterdam')->isoFormat('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
```